# Building an associative array using for loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an associative array using php. My desired output is

```
Array
(
     [key] => fl_0_sq
),
Array
(
     [key] => fl_1_sq
)
```

The code is

```
  $max_val = 2;  
  for($i=0; $i<$max_val; $i++)
  {
        $flr_arr .= "array('key' => 'fl_".$i."_sq'),";      
  }
  print_r($flr_arr);
```

Output is

```
array('key' => 'fl_0_sq'),array('key' => 'fl_1_sq'),
```

Now the issue is that it has become a string instead of an array. Is it at all possible to create a array structure like the desired output. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<?php

$flr_arr = [];

$max_val = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_val; $i++) {
  $flr_arr[][key] = 'fl_' . $i . '_sq';
}

$output = "<pre>";

foreach ($flr_arr as $i => $flr_arr_item) {
  $output .= print_r($flr_arr_item, true);
  if($i < count($flr_arr)-1){
    $output = substr($output, 0, -1) . ",\n";
  }
}
$output .= "</pre>";

echo $output;
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [key] => fl_0_sq
),
Array
(
    [key] => fl_1_sq
)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Tomasz solution is pretty close. I need to insert a comma though after each array ends.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Here you go ;) now it has the exact formatting you want

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Yes that works really great. I had some other key elements so I have to adjust anyway. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but your output could be done by this:

```
  $max_val = 2;
  for($i=0; $i<$max_val; $i++)
  {
        $flr_arr = [];
        $flr_arr['key'] = 'fl_".$i."_sq';
        print_r($flr_arr);
  }
```

Comment: Almost there. Thanks a lot. Last thing I need to know that is how can I insert a comma after each array ends.

Comment: echo ',' isn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a string and concatenating it. You want to add elements to an array. You also can't create multiple arrays with the same name. What you can do, though is a 2D array:

```
$flr_arr[] = array("key"=>"fl_$i_sq");
```

Note the lack of quotes around array(). The "[]" syntax adds a new element to the end of the array. The output would be -

```
array(array('key' => 'fl_0_sq'),array('key' => 'fl_1_sq'))
```